# CSS - Apply background colour to tab

Tags: html, css

I have the following  html:

```css
div.tabHdr {
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   margin-right: 5px;
   border-color: #ddd #ddd transparent;
   padding: 10px; 15px;
   width: auto;
 }

 div.activeHdr {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #555;
 
 }

 div.inactiveHdr {
    background: #FFF;
 }

 .inactiveHdr a:hover {
    background: #eee;
    text-decoration: none; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="tabHdr inactiveHdr">
   <a href="/" title="">my link</a>
</div>
```

When I hover over the link only the background around the link changes color but I want the whole tab background to change. How can I achieve this?

Comment: remove the a:hover and just leave .inactiveHdr:hover or tabHdr:hover

Comment: Or move the padding to the `div.tabHdr a`

Comment: you want the background colour to change only when you hover on the link and not on anywhere on the div??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this snippet

```
.inactiveHdr:hover {
    background: #eee;
 }
 .inactiveHdr:hover a {
    text-decoration: none; 
 }
```

```css
div.tabHdr {
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   margin-right: 5px;
   border-color: #ddd #ddd transparent;
   padding: 10px; 15px;
   width: auto;
 }

 div.activeHdr {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #555;

 }

 div.inactiveHdr {
    background: #FFF;
 }

 .inactiveHdr:hover {
    background: #eee;
 }
  .inactiveHdr:hover a {
    text-decoration: none; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="tabHdr inactiveHdr">
   <a href="/" title="">my link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 .inactiveHdr a:hover {
```

To

```
 .inactiveHdr:hover {
```

Edit, if you want to remove the natural underline on the link, you'll need to keep:

```
.inactiveHdr a:hover {
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So just move the `hover` to the containing `div`:

```
.tabHdr:hover {
    background: #eee;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when child is hover parent is also in hover state

```
.inactiveHdr:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
```

but now when you hover tab but no hover link you can't click in link so i suggest remove outer div and change display of link to

```
display: block;
```

like in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/45nmv9zw/

Answer (score -1):

**Replace this**

```
div.tabHdr:hover {
 background: #eee;
 text-decoration: none; 
}
```

**Instead of**

```
.inactiveHdr a:hover {
  background: #eee;
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```